# Scripts only working half the time

Tags: javascript, html

I have added 2 scripts to the head of my website. The first one will change the scale to 0.75 if the width of the device is less than 480 pixels and the second one will reload the page if the orientation of the device is changed.
Both only seem to work half the time when reloading the page or changing the orientation of my Android device. Ive tried using them on their own and different browsers.
Is something wrong with the code? Is it my device?

```
<meta id="myViewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            if(window.innerWidth < 480) {
                var mvp = document.getElementById('myViewport');
                mvp.setAttribute('content','initial-scale=0.75');
            }
        }
     </script>
          <script>  
    window.onorientationchange = function() { 
        var orientation = window.orientation; 
            switch(orientation) { 
                case 0: window.location.reload(); 
                break; 
                case 90: window.location.reload(); 
                break; 
                case -90: window.location.reload(); 
                break; } 
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: What happens when they don't work? Is the function not being called, or it's called and doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: I'm pretty sure someone will murder you if you reload a webpage on orientation change...

Comment: Why doesn't your orientation function handle `180`?

Comment: You don't need to split these scripts into two separate scripts, unless there's a good reason.

Comment: When they dont work it doesnt do what they are supposed to do. The scale wont change or the website wont reload.

Answer (score 0):

Try mergin it in one script called in the onload event:

```
window.onload = function () {
    if (window.innerWidth < 480) {
        var mvp = document.getElementById('myViewport');
        mvp.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=0.75');
    }

    window.onorientationchange = function () {
        var orientation = window.orientation;
        switch (orientation) {
            case 0:
            case 90:
            case -90:
                window.location.reload();
                break;
        }
    };
};
```

Then try running it and tell me what happens.

Comment: I would love some help with that. As you can tell, I am pretty new to this.

Comment: Thank you. But it didnt change anything. It still doesnt work 50% of the time. One reload its properly scaled to 0.75, the other time is the default scale. Thats the original reason why I implemented that reloading script, since I hoped it would be more consistent when at least switching orientations. But guess not.

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks. I figured it out myself. It was actually a problem with the fluid layout causing it.